# JPA Entity with Id column only

Tags: jpa, modeling

I have JPA entity that for the time being has no property other than Id (and high chance that
no other attribute will be added in the future) and it has many to many (from business perspective) relation to full entity - that is an entity with id and other fields.

Does it make sense to model an entity with Id field only? if not what are the alternatives?

Comment: I see no reason to do anything differently here; just create an entity class with one field.

Comment: you mean the primary key only?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: Thank you, I thought it strange to have an entity with only primary key column

Comment: the main reason for having another table is to manage changes. Since the id you are creating the id for doesn't change, you should store ids in a column and create an AttributeConverter for it.

Comment: It is unusual to have a SQL table with just a PK field.  But sequences, calendar tables, etc. all fit this description.